# How do I add buttons to an MS Access form at run time with VBA and add code to the _Click() event

Tags: forms, vba, ms-access, events, runtime

I need to add buttons to a form at run time for Access.  When clicked each button will need to open a modal form with specific information based on the button clicked.  So for instance, if I write a loop to create five buttons and name them button1, button2, button3, button4 and button5; how would I achieve the following:

```
Private Sub button1_Click()
    Msgbox "Button 1 was Clicked"
End Sub

Private Sub button2_Click()
    Msgbox "Button 2 was Clicked"
End Sub

Private Sub button3_Click()
    Msgbox "Button 3 was Clicked"
End Sub

Private Sub button4_Click()
    Msgbox "Button 4 was Clicked"
End Sub

Private Sub button5_Click()
    Msgbox "Button 5 was Clicked"
End Sub
```

This is a simplified version of what I want to achieve but this is the gist of it.  Am I thinking about this correctly?  Is there better way?

I am using MS Access 2010.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Why not build all buttons and Click events and just dynamically hide/show them? See the [Visible property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff196785.aspx) of controls.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is how you can create an Event Procedure (Click()) for a Control (Command Button) named cmdDemo on the Current Form

```
Dim ctl As Control
Dim mdl As Module
Dim frm As Form

Set ctl = Me![cmdDemo]      'Set a Reference to the Command Button
Set frm = Me                'Set a reference to the Form
Set mdl = Me.Module         'Set a Reference to the Form's Code Module

'Create a Click() Event Procedure for the Command Button cmdDemo
lngReturn = mdl.CreateEventProc("Click", ctl.Name)

'Insert a single Line of Code in the Event Procedure
mdl.InsertLines lngReturn + 1, "Msgbox ""Create Procedure Demo"""
```